# parse server: exclude relation from query javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

i am trying to query a class of users which contains a relation column called "blocking" which contains a list of user objects from the same class

when i try to query all users i would like to query which is not present in this relation column

i did the following

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
var relation = currentUser.relation('blocking')
query.doesNotExist(relation);
query.find().then((users)=>{
  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    let object = users[i];
    console.log(object)

  }
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

but it did not work

any help will be appreciated

Comment: the problem in these two line of codes:   var relation = currentUser.relation('blocking')
query.doesNotExist(relation);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to do it myself

at first i query the relation and store a list of blocked ids in an array

```
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
      var relation = currentUser.relation("blocking");
      relation.query().find().then(blockedusers=>{
        var blockedIds = []
        for (var i = 0; i<blockedusers.length; i++){
          blockedIds.push(blockedusers[i].id)
        } 
      })
```

after that i moved the whole query inside the relation find and do (not contained in) this array like the following

```
         query.notContainedIn("objectId", blockedIds)
```

that solved my problem

thanks